# How to get pk from url in django rest framework?

Tags: django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have 2 apps Ticket and Comment, with url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tickets/<int:pk>/comments/<int:pk>/`.

*comment.views*

```
class CommentAPIList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)   
    pagination_class = CommentAPIListPagination
```

I want to get first int:pk in my url for filter my queryset, like:

```
queryset = Comment.objects.filter(ticket=MY_GOAL_PK)
```

*comment.models*

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(
        Ticket,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

*ticket.models*

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    text = models.TextField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I don't know what other information I can give, but I can give it at your request.
May be you have another solution for filtering my **Comment.objects**.
Filtering should provide comments related only to this Ticket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You override the `get_queryset(…)` method:

```
class CommentAPIList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    pagination_class = CommentAPIListPagination

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .filter(ticket_id=self.kwargs['ticket_pk'])
        )
```

For the path, the primary key of the ticket should have a different name, for example:

```
api/tickets/<int:ticket_pk>/comments/<int:pk>/
```